# How do I shut off reply when sending an email to a large group?

Tags: automation, reply

When sending an email to a large group, how do I shut off the automatic reply messages.  I don't want to receive a reply.

Tammy

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include more details like what email client are you using, what OS, etc.

Comment: You do not, since **you* are not sending the replies. You ask the receiving people to configure their clients properly.

Comment: Are you using the medium as write-only? Use a mailaddress like `noreply@mydomain` and have it properly redirected in aliases db.

Answer (score 1):

This can not be done.

Automatic replies are being sent by the recipient of your original email.  Your email client can not differentiate between a user sent email or a computer generated one.

Comment: Actually, you can sometimes tell your email client how to differentiate between auto-responses and real responses, and filter your incoming email accordingly. You'll still get the auto replies, but you can send them straight to the round file. And there will always be the odd email server that formats its auto responses totally differently than anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Emails can have a `reply-to` setting, which is where well-behaved email systems will direct replies, including automatic ones. How and whether you can access this setting in your email program is a different question, but if you can figure that part out, then you can simply set that to a bogus address such as "noreply@yourdomain.com". In general, this is more reliable than spoofing the `from` address itself, since some mail servers will detect a mismatch between where an email came from and where it *says* it came from, and will mark such emails as spam/refuse to deliver them.

If you want to still receive individual replies, just not the auto-responder ones, you can tell your recipients to use the "From" address. (This is another aspect where spoofing the "From" address fails: if you set that to a bogus mailbox, then your recipients will not know where to direct replies without drilling into the email headers or something.)

Comment: Uh, downvote?? This answer is absolutely correct, I do it all the time at work.

Comment: This is a bad idea, as this would send all replies - both legitimate and automated - replies somewhere else.

Comment: @Keltari, (a) since he's sending the email to a large group, he presumably doesn't want replies, and (b) humans are smarter than auto-responders and can send replies to the "from" address.

Comment: never, ever assume

Comment: +1 _I don't want to receive a reply._ pretty much speaks for itself: No replies at all. This solution works well for most cases especially newsletters. You can still put a contact address in the emails signature.

Comment: @Keltari: when a question lacks details, we have to assume things. You assumed that she wants to receive non-automatic replies, for example, even though by some interpretations her question contradicts that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent replies, but you can misdirect them. Depending on the mail client and first uplink mail server you are using, you can generate a bogus "do not reply" From: address for your email. Most bulk email programs offer this option. Whether your ISP will accept such a message is another question.

Comment: What I want to know is, if my answer was downvote-worthy, why hasn't this answer been downvoted as well? This suggestion has all the same pitfalls as changing the reply-to, with none of the benefits.

Comment: @Martha I think your answer is worthy of an upvote, so I just did so. Apparently those concerned with the downsides of setting reply-to (which are very similar to forging the From: as I suggested) disliked your answer enough to downvote. In addition the question has been closed, even though I feel it is a valid question. The only real issues I see is that the asker initially wanted something impossible (make email work one-way) but would probably be happy with any of these answers for alternatives.